# Google Adwords tracking cookie triggers ASP.NET Request Validation exception

Tags: asp.net, validation, google-ads-api

Sorry for my English.
I have a strange problem.
When user click adword link, Google write tracking cookie like that
`1813234232.1302674912.30.51.utmgclid=CcgezrsXjagCFcs-zAod_h2oCQ|utmccn=(not set)|utmcmd=(not set)|utmctr= CAA:89 AB0=40@B%20>:`
In keyword section(utmctr) there is bad braskets, that cause request validation exception
`A potentially dangerous Request.Cookies value was detected from the client (__utmz="...0=40@B%20> at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateCookieCollection(HttpCookieCollection cc)`

Is there any way to solve this problem without turning off request validation?

**Edited**
I'm probably found obvious solution: write own request validation module http://jefferytay.wordpress.com/2010/04/15/creating-your-own-custom-request-validation/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default asp.net validate and check the data for potential attacts.

You can disable this automatic validation by set `validateRequest="false"` ether on page

```
<%@ Page validateRequest="false" %>
```

ether on web.config that affect all pages.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <pages validateRequest="false" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

The only think that you need to check by your self after that, is if someone enters any script data to your inputs. Your inputs then need to check out when you render them on the page, and when you enter them on the database.